# Querying for phrase with more than one space returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a searching form that the user should enter a word. Till now it works just fine but when I enter a word with 2 or more white spaces the query returns none (empty).

```
    $search = $_POST['srch'];

    if (!$search == "")
    {
    $con = mysql_connect('nnnnn', 'nnnnn', 'nnnn');
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("nnnnnnn", $con);
    $search = mysql_real_escape_string($search);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `computers` WHERE `MODEL` REGEXP '$search|$search\$' OR
    `DESCR`\n"
        . "REGEXP '^$search|$search\$' LIMIT 0, 30 ";
    // here check if there is any content
if (mysql_fetch_array($result))

{

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{// here just echoing the returned content 

}

}else echo "not found";

    }echo "enter a word"! ;
```

So if I enter `core 2` for example it retruns all the matching results.

But if I write `core 2 dou` it doesn't return anything, not even the "Not found error".

How can I fix this?

I tried the PHPMyAdmin by replacing the `$search`

and the query return matches even with `core 2 dou` and even with adding messy words like

`core 2 dou computers`

i am sure the problem is in the php way of sending the query or handling it i just cant figure it out

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It seems your regexp is searching for `starts with $search` or `ends with $search` in `model` and `descr`. Is that your intended search criteria?

Comment: If the question is not clear you may notice me to put more info's

Comment: What happens if you query for `core 2 duo`?

Comment: It did not return any thing
while it works fine with "core 2"

Comment: Please edit your post with the _exact_ code you're using, and notice I asked `core 2 duo`, not `core 2 dou` that you have in your question.

Comment: If you need to do serious searching like this across a large dataset, you will probably want to look at a tool like Solr or Sphinx. Fuzzy text searches in MySQL are not very performant.

Comment: i will host on a shared server witch i dont have any control so there is no chance to install any tools or set any setting in Mysql Or PHP configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said any help would be appreciated, if you just want to search for a string, an easier way is to use LIKE instead of REGEXP, for example,

```
MODEL LIKE '%$search%'
```

also, I'm not sure why you're repeating $search separated by a '|'

incidentally, if multiple spaces are the problem, it's easy to replace with single space, like this:

```
$search = implode(' ', preg_split("/\s+/", $search));
```

Comment: i have already tried that but it will only search for exact match not partial match so that why am using REGEXP

Comment: by partial match, you mean it should match both `'core 2'` and `'core  2`' (varying number of spaces between words?

Comment: yes exactly but this is not my problem read the edited question to get a better idea about what i want

Comment: If you want to use LIKE you will need to split your search term on space and use `LIKE 'part1' AND LIKE 'part2' AND LIKE 'part3'`, but this is very slow. Details on usage here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: i will then have to add query for each part cuz i cant add a fixed number of LIKE in the query and this is extremely slow

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the pattern in quotes.  Whereas you have

```
"... REGEXP ^$search|$search\$ ..."
```

You need to have

```
"... REGEXP \"^$search|$search\$\" ..."
```

Additionally, you should escape `$search` at least using `mysql_real_escape_string` unless you want site visitors to be able to [run random SQL against your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: i just removed the quotes for asking the question here 
And yes i had already did that 
and i have mysql_real_escaping_string

Comment: So you asked a question, and pasted code that you are not using?  How are we supposed to help you if you're not even going to show us your code?

Comment: this my code i just removed the quotes so it displays the whole code in gray but ok i will edit the question and include the whole code